# Start a Windows console program from a Mac

Tags: windows, mac, ssh, boot

Is there any straight way that one can start a Windows console program from a Mac?
Preferrably I would like to something with ssh, but as I am in a private network without Internet, I am not so afraid of security.
I have used VNC, but my users deem it as too slow/uncomfortable.

Comment: doesn't this question belong to superuser.com ?

Comment: Remote Desktop has far better performance (although it is still GUI remote access). I use it to access a Windows machine for Visual Studio development, and, although not quite like sitting directly at it, it's quite usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell for windows has SSH server capabilities for remote management. Look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff808410.aspx) for an article by Microsoft about it. You can get Powershell [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx). There are also several walkthroughs online on how to [set up the server](http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/tutorials/pssshexchange.aspx).