# How to start a Windows program from a remote system?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ssh, vmware-fusion, remote-access

I have Windows 7 (x64) running in VMware Fusion on my Mac. To make debugging apps on the Windows side from the Java side easier, I'd like to be able to start the app in Windows from the Mac side.

I'm open to running an ssh server (if that's the only solution), but the links from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/205706/start-a-windows-console-program-from-a-mac) question seem old and possibly out-of-date. An answer to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/257426/execute-windows-program-from-unix-script-on-remote-server) recommended [winexe](https://lbtwiki.cern.ch/bin/view/Online/WinExe), but I'm not sure if that'll work on windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of further research the [`session`](http://www.raaftech.nl/session/) software looks promising for running commands on remote Windows PCs from a Mac using the `winexe` command.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to start programs on a remote PC using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) under Windows. So, it may be possible to run that from [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) on the Mac, but that's a blatant piece of speculation.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, PsExec doesn't work in wine.

Comment: There's a linux equivalent called winexe available from sourceforge here http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/ that claims "probably compatibility with other unices" so it might possibly maybe work under os x

Comment: OK, this looks much more promising http://www.raaftech.nl/session/ has a mac version and includes winexe

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to use session, but can you please post that comment as a separate answer so I can accept it?